# $line.StartsWith on multiple options

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to be able to scan for two separate values in a line how do I do this?

```
$file = Get-Content "D:\path\tmp\certlist.txt"

foreach ($line in $file)
{
    if ($line.StartsWith("snl") or $line.StartsWith("HSM1"))
    {
        $baseKey = "app.swift.snl."
        $profileName = $line.Substring(0,13).TrimEnd()
        $certType = $line.Substring(29,10).TrimEnd()
        $renewalDate = Get_Unixtime $line.Substring(42,11).TrimEnd()
        $expiryDate = Get_Unixtime $line.Substring(58,11).TrimEnd()
        Send_Zabbix ($baseKey + $profileName + "." + $certType + ".renewaldate") $renewalDate
        Send_Zabbix ($baseKey + $profileName + "." + $certType + ".expirydate") $expiryDate
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work. It gives me an unexpected token.

Answer (score 3):

For checking if a variable starts with one of several values a regular expression might be a better approach than daisy-chained `StartsWith()` calls.

```
if ($line -cmatch '^(snl|HSM1)')
{
    ...
}
```

`^` matches the beginning of a string, `(snl|HSM1)` matches either `snl` or `HSM1`. `-cmatch` does a case-sensitive match. If you don't need case-sensitivity use `-imatch` or just `-match`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently all I needed was a '-'

```
if ($line.StartsWith("snl") -or $line.StartsWith("HSM1"))
```

Comment: Are you using the Powershell ISE? Its highlighting would give you an idea of where errors like that are :)